# Keyboard shortcuts... how to find out more?

Tags: support, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

I was just perusing about on main, when I inadvertently pressed the <kbd>i</kbd>  key on my keyboard. This is what happened:

[image]

i.e., my inbox popped up, with fancy number-key shortcuts to access inbox items (style very reminiscent of old text-based RPGs). I started pressing other letters and more things happened that I had never seen before. I have never touched any sort of keyboard settings or anything of the like, to my knowledge, so it seems these are built-in (?).

Can someone point me to some sort of documentation on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are Stack Exchange keyboard shortcuts. From the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237166/259867):

> When you go to the *Edit Profile & Settings* page on your profile, and then select the *Preferences* submenu, you’ll find a new checkbox labeled *Enable keyboard shortcuts* (which is located about half the way down on that page). Click it, and from there on, everything works as with the user script. Press <kbd>?</kbd> to get started.
>
> You'll have to make this change on every Stack Exchange site that you're active on.

The available shortcuts depend on where you are on the site, but pressing <kbd>?</kbd>, as mentioned above, will show what they are. For example, these are things you can do on a question page:

[image: example]

Comment: Wow, I will definitely exploit this, thank you. There's always new things about this site that I'm completely in the dark on...