# Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 01/2021 - 12/2021)

Tags: discussion, re-open, big-list, undeletion

The purpose of this thread is to focus the attention of the community on posts that may require reopen and undeletion votes. A request should be posted as an answer below (one request per answer).

Some guidelines:

- Please be polite, and respect the many different viewpoints in our diverse community. This goes for the person making the request as well as those commenting on it.
- There is a reopen queue. Please wait until a post has gone through this queue, before posting here. Notice that the first edit after the question is closed pushes the question into the reopen review queue if the edit is done within 5 days of closure, and so does a reopen vote.  (If the review has already been finished, it is shown on the [timeline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24826/how-to-see-questions-time-line) of the question.) When in doubt, wait 24 hours after the last substantive action.
- To inform readers of the current (and past) states of the targeted post, please add the information  **Reopened** or **Undeleted** at the start *once the request has resulted in some action*. (If the action is undone, add this too, like **Reopened, Reclosed**.)
- Do not only post a request, like "request reopening of `link`". Instead, make a case for your concern. Yet keep in mind that it can be easier to get your request handled if you try to frame it in a way that takes the feedback the post received into account positively rather then seeking confrontation. Also, try to improve the post before posting here.
- In case of "small" requests, like one missing vote, it can make sense to ask in chat instead of posting here. The room [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured) is a reasonable place for such requests. The same guidelines apply there.
- If you are involved in the thread which you post about (e.g., you asked the question or you answered it), please disclose this.

---

Earlier versions of the thread that served as a model:

- [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 07/2018 - 12/2020)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692)
- [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 01/2015 - 07/2018 )](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042)
- [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 10/2012 - 12/2014)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6424)

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is not ok to post undeletion requests if one of the deletion votes was from a mod right? I assume that it is not, but I just want to be sure. Also, feel free to delete this comment if it is appropriate, or ask me to delete it and I will.

Comment: @HereToRelax To weigh in on that, I don't see why it wouldn't be OK, but only a moderator could help you. One would guess that it would be more appropriate to flag, but that doesn't really allow for back and forth discussion.

Comment: You are always welcome to discuss questions which a moderator has voted to delete.  If you are asking about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318512), it is worth noting that my delete vote was cast in 2019, *before* I was a moderator.  I stand by that vote---even with the minor clarification in the comments, the question still lacks context---but you are welcome to discuss the question.  If you can find two people who agree with you, the question can be undeleted.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: There may never be a perfect time to close this (last year's thread) and start a new one, but things are about as quiet as they could be.

Comment: @hardmath I am out of town right now, and not very engaged with Math SE.  However, I agree that a new thread should be made.  My understanding is that creation of the new "Reopen & Undelete" thread is a kind of hazing ritual for new moderators, so maybe one of the new mods should do it. :D

Comment: @hardmath There is no reason to keep creating new threads. In fact it is better not to, since then there are always (many) prior requests visible (and easily accessible) - which sheds light on the current community consensus on such exceptional matters (which e.g. may discourage noise: requests doomed to fail).  See also [old discussion on such](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19045/242)

Answer (score 12):

**Reopened, Re-closed (by a mod), and Reopened again with context edit reinstated**

Please consider reopening [Any criteria for a category to have all connected limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164403/any-criteria-for-a-category-to-have-all-connected-limits).  This is a very natural question about whether there is an analogue of certain well-known basic theorems in category theory in a less well-known context.  The context in the original question was quite clear to anyone familiar with the area but was only in a brief parenthetical at the end of the question.  I have expanded on this and improved the presentation a bit to make it more accessible to non-experts.

It seems to me that this is exactly the sort of question that this site was built for: questions that may naturally occur to many people (not just some exercise that is of no particular interest), do not have obvious or "standard" answers that can be found in every textbook on the subject, and by having an answer here the answer will be easily findable with a search engine.

[Disclosure: I have answered the question.]

Comment: The question was appropriately closed for lacking context.  You then edited the question to insert material which is not clearly the product of the original asker's intentions.  This version of the question was reopened.  As the edits were inappropriate, they were rolled back.  I have reclosed the question.

Comment: For future reference, please read the [guidelines on rewrites and context edits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/guidelines-for-context-edits-and-rewrites).

Comment: Reading the guidelines, it says that one can clarify the phrasing and add relavant basic definitions, which looks to me like what you have done. In particular no ‘attempt’ was added. So, is it that too much context was added so that the question was changed fundamentally?

Comment: @CalvinKhor: Indeed, I was trying to follow the guidelines and it is not clear at all to me how I violated them.  I have messaged the mods to ask for clarification.  (And if this edit violates the intended meaning of the guidelines, I think the guidelines themselves need some significant edits to make that clearer.)

Comment: +1, voted to reopen - this should be reopened and Eric Wofsey's edit should be restored. It seems like exactly the sort of context-adding edit that would be appropriate under the guidelines: it added a relevant definition, some simple background and motivation, and one small related theorem of similar level to those already mentioned by the OP, exactly [as suggested](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/). If this isn't acceptable, what is?

Comment: Overly zealous application of guidelines leads to removal of significant mathematical content from m.se. Again. Sad.

Comment: Searching in CURED for this question gives a few hits: https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=4164403&room=2165 (Also, to be fair, the content has not (yet) been removed)

Comment: Crucially the decision to rollback the edits made by Eric to improve the Question was not made by a moderator but by a user who espouses the view that no one should be allowed to improve the body of the Question except the OP.  I know this from personal experience of adding material from Comments left by the OP into the body of the Question, and being "told off" for doing so.  But it is not in the spirit of this Community to judge improvements so harshly.

Comment: The other problem is with an inactive OP and how we could work out editing posts of inactive/suspended/removed OPs.  Perhaps reasking the question with context and self-answering is a possibility, as was recently done on meta. This would be my suggestion in that case : then find the OP of the original question and redirect them to your question.

Comment: The situation with this question is shocking to me. Eric's edits were fairly minor and a clear improvement. They did not change the intent or core content of the question at all - but they did greatly improve the presentation. To me, they seem squarely in line with the guidelines. The OP has even signaled approval in the comments. I do not understand the motivation to roll back the question to its earlier, lower quality form...

Comment: @AlexKruckman It's not shocking to me—it's yet another example of the moderators/power users of MathSE enforcing the rules inconsistently to how they are written. The fact that *mathematicians* do this, given that one could argue the entire point of the last two centuries of mathematics has been to systematically root out inconsistency, is however bewildering.

Answer (score 9):

**Reopened, reclosed, reopened again, closed once again, and reopened once again**

Please consider reopening [this Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4100315/how-many-iterations-would-it-take-to-get-each-player-in-a-squad-to-play-on-the-s), which was closed for lack of context.

Yet the original opening paragraph gives the following context:

> I have a young group of kids (30) playing soccer and they need to be put into 6 teams of 5 players for each round of matches. All 6 teams play at the same time on adjoining fields.

I make a point of bringing this to the Community's attention because there has been something of a historical pattern with these kinds of problems.  The asker has (or claims to have) a real world motivation for asking about a certain kind of block design.  The Question has a definite mathematical formulation and solution, often one that is not obvious without a certain amount of trial and error computation (though occasionally the literature provides an answer).

None of the five close voters left a Comment to record what in the way of additional context would improve the Question to their satisfaction.

Comment: Most combinatorial design questions require decades of research and computational time to answer, so it infuriates me when questions like these are closed with a comment like "well, what have you tried?". Presented with such a hard problem in real life, most mathematicians would be stumped, let alone laymen.

Comment: @MikeEarnest:  Right, a typical user might well not know *how* to tackle problems that they have a real world motivation for.  I want to see their context, but "what have you tried" is not the gold standard here (though this user did suggest they'd thought about *complete* block designs because they said it wasn't what they wanted).

Answer (score 8):

**Undeleted (still closed), Deleted, Undeleted, Deleted again, Undeleted again, and yet deleted again, and locked – permanently! – by moderator Xander Henderson**

The question [What are sufficient conditions for a number to be irrational or transcendental?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236125/what-are-sufficient-conditions-for-number-to-be-algebraic-irrational-or-transcen) was closed as a duplicate of [Proving irrationality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62878/proving-irrationality) and then deleted (along with answers with scores of $+12,+7,+4,+4$).

I suggest the newer question is not a duplicate of the older one. The newer question asks about proving irrationality, proving transcendence, and asks for books on these topics. The older question asks only about proving irrationality.

Please consider voting to undelete the question.

In the interests of full disclosure, I posted an answer to the question (scored $+2$).

Comment: It would be nice to know why those voting against this request think that a question about transcendence and references is a duplicate of a question which is about neither of those things.

Comment: Upvoting this post, but not voting to reopen. Gerry, I'm uncomfortable with questions of this type. The scope is too wide in my opinion. Non-overlapping books have been written about proving irrationality and transcendence respectively. On the other hand, if we improve the question by giving it a more specialized focus, then each and every choice of focus is likely to lead to a question that has been handled already. True, we do allow reference requests, but I prefer those with a rather narrow focus. Otherwise they become lists of textbooks ranked by popularity rather than merit.

Comment: (cont'd) Anyway, the site may benefit from having a wider discussion about what we like to see in a reference request. It is not easy to give a definitive list of criteria. My judgement is that the linked is too unfocused, but there is a lot of scope for differences of opinion.

Comment: I suggested the duplicate : I'd done so because I noticed that your answer was the only one that discussed references. Every other answer discusses techniques that have been covered in the duplicate answer, some in more detail so I give them this credit. I don't think the focus of the question was clear enough, so that one could definitively say it was a reference request over a general question about sufficient conditions for irrationality (which would make it a dupe). I saw the answerers focus on the latter when I entered, hence I suggested that particular post as a duplicate.

Comment: I was scouring the site for duplicates of reference requests for irrationality and rationality of numbers, but I found only one question which was anyway labelled a bit imprecise, ref. Jyrki's third and fourth sentence of his first comment. It received only one answer, a fairly short one. I can say for sure that if the author decided to focus on the book recommendation, it wouldn't have been a duplicate (maybe closed for lack of clarity, but I'd not do so). So the way the majority of answerers read and answered the question definitely influenced my thought process behind it's duplicacy.

Comment: @Jyrki, it's true that proving irrationality and transcendence are different, and the most advanced books would generally be about only one of the two, but more introductory texts (the kind that would be most helpful to OP) generally pay attention to both.

Comment: @Teresa, I think it's a little odd to judge a question by the answers it gets. Also, I think there's no such word as "duplicacy". There's "duplicity", but that means something entirely different.

Comment: Sorry about the usage of "duplicacy" , you can replace it with "property of being a duplicate". I don't think it's odd at all : the title of the question is "what are some techniques..." and six of the seven (incl. deleted) answers have tried to address this particular question and not the book recommendation, all of which could easily have been answers to the duplicate. The comments also don't discuss books, neither did the OP. I don't deny that the OP asked for books, but it seems to have been brushed so far under the carpet that your answer has downvotes on it, for possibly being off topic.

Comment: The answers are based upon what the others thought about the question : which is that it primarily focused on sufficient conditions for irrationality/transcendentality. You are free to ask for reopening, and I'd be happy if more people agreed with you, but I can't agree , not when I sense that the next person answering this question is also going to write , not about book recommendations but about more techniques , which could easily go into the duplicate. That's the feeling I'm left with, after seeing the majority of the answers. I could be wrong, I'd be happy to be proved so.

Comment: @Teresa, it's impossible to know why other users downvoted my answer. And possibly the other answerers weren't as well-informed about references as I was, or just thought they could help more by sharing what they knew about the mathematics than by directing OP to the library. Who knows? Anyway, I haven't asked for the question to be reopened, I'm just glad it has been undeleted (and hope it stays that way).

Comment: I cannot see this being deleted again (and would not be happy about it being deleted again), and I wouldn't want to open it (ref. comment above your last one) so I guess we are closer to being on the same page. Thank you and +1 to your request.

Comment: This question was deleted 11 hours ago and undeleted 9 hours ago (I undeleted the question with my vote).

Comment: @Teresa, evidently your crystal ball was clouded.

Comment: It was, I agree I was wrong.

Comment: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" No, thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, in case you're wondering, but the question is a very bad one. It is not only wrongly motivated, by wanting to solve an open problem, but it is also **opinion-based** and **asking for personal advice**.

Comment: @user21820, maybe so, but the one thing even you evidently agree to is that it's not a duplicate. Closing and deleting it as a duplicate was an error. Keep it closed, if you like, but don't delete it, as that deletes some useful answers as well, answers that don't duplicate what's at the earlier question. [the answers currently stand at 15, 10, 7, 7, and 4.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be deleted? Are you saying we should ignore [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) just because some people refuse to abide by them? If everyone didn't answer bad questions, there would be no "useful answers" at risk of deletion.

Comment: @user21820, I'm saying we shouldn't delete a question as a duplicate when it isn't a duplicate, and we shouldn't vandalize the site by deleting helpful mathematical content.

Comment: Users should not vandalize the site by going against quality standards.

Comment: @user21820 I agree with you... Users should not vandalize the site by going against quality standards by deleting questions based on their own opinions not on quality standards... I mean many users want the question .... but other users exploit their high reputation and authority on the site.... and it is not forbidden and wrong to be motivated by open problem...high level users also should respect the effort done by answerers ....the answerers also are high level they are:1)Thomas Andrews 158k reputation  , 2)Gerry Myerson 165k reputation,  3)Lubin 57k reputation 4)slugger 5k reputation.

Comment: @user21820, imagine that you haven't been exposed to a good treatment of questions of irrationality and transcendence. But you've seen some popularization that talks about $\sqrt2$ being irrational, and $\pi$ and $e$ being transcendental, maybe without even giving proper definitions of those terms, let alone proofs, and it mentions that it's an open question whether $\pi+e$ is rational. The topic interests you, and you want to learn more about it. You just might post a question like the one we're discussing here. You want to know how to do irrationality and transcendence proofs (continued)

Comment: (continued) and you want to know where to read up on these things, and that's about all you know how to ask. Now, I would want to encourage such a person to keep up an interest in math, and aim that person in a good direction. By closing and deleting the question, you're chasing OP away from mathematics (and in particular from this website). I think that's terrible. Please, have a little empathy for someone who is interested in math and just needs some direction. Vote to undelete.

Comment: The post probably should have been closed as too board. But it is really not too bad of a question. Voted to undelete.

Comment: @gerry agreed , I will delete the above comments. This is my fault , to critique everything everybody says for no reason. Lesson learnt , it has been a good day when you make many mistakes so I hope to learn on the job.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I find it slightly ironic that you state both " I think it's a little odd to judge a question by the answers it gets", but that you take the time in your response here to list the scores of the answers which would be / have been deleted along with this question.

Comment: @Xander, Teresa was interpreting a question via the topics the answers chose to emphasize, I was evaluating a thread by the reception those answers got. The irony is slight, indeed.

Comment: I have locked the question in its current state in order to prevent a continuation of this [un]delete war.

Answer (score 6):

**Undeleted**

I'd like to **tentatively** nominate [A structural view to the power set axiom: Is this axiom really justifiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574822/a-structural-view-to-the-power-set-axiom-is-this-axiom-really-justifiable) for undeletion *(admission: I have an answer there)*. It was a fine question.

Re: the "tentatively" above, I'm not actually sure that undeletion is possible/ethical: at a glance it looks like what may have happened is that the OP deleted their account and requested that all of their posts be deleted as well. If that's the case - I'm not able to tell since I lack mod tools - then I don't think undeletion would be appropriate, but since I'm not sure it is (given that there it's not locked, so undeletion is possible) I'd like to bring it up.

Comment: How did it get deleted in the first place?

Comment: @Onir It says "deleted by community." I'm not exactly sure what that means. My best guess is what I state above, in which case unfortunately undeletion would probably be unethical, but on the off-chance that there could be a different reason I decided to bring it up anyways.

Comment: oh, but I don't think you can get all of your stuff deleted just because you want it.

Comment: @Onir I recall some confusion on this point; I'm certainly not sure myself.

Comment: From what I can see from [the post timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1574822/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries), the user was destroyed and as a result all of their content was deleted (see [deleted vs destroyed on the main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)). The same post implies it is unlikely that a user can request their account be destroyed - it seems to be more applicable for spammers or other problem users. I don't think you need to be too worried about the ethics of undeleting here.

Comment: Remember that any post is legally the intellectual property of the SE corporate overlords, and not the property to the person who posted it.  While users may delete content, there is no legal or ethical problem with the community undeleting it if it is considered useful.  In this case, there is even less of an issue, as the user account no longer exists.

Answer (score 5):

#### Undeleted

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3980921/43608

This is a deleted new answer to an old question (from february 2019), by a user that has been on MSE for 1 year and 10 months, but does not seem to have questions or answers yet.

The deleted answer is short, arguably too short, but would be at least a good hint in the correct direction (it was for me, when I tried to figure out whether to vote to delete or not in review queue).

The question is ambiguous, as noticed by the two answers already here, but I think the new one has the correct interpretation (that the coefficients $a,b,c$ are independent of $n$), since it leads easily to a unique solution, as expected.

I believe the deleted answer is correct while the two undeleted ones are not, and thus deserves to be undeleted.

Comment: Looks to be undeleted now.

Answer (score 5):

**Undeleted**

[RKHS of functions vanishing at single point](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4132664/22857)

Asker deleted the question soon after receiving an answer. The question is homework-like, but the asker showed a decent effort in my view.

I didn't vote to undelete since the answer is mine, and I wanted to see what others think.

Comment: What I think is, we don't like it when a user deletes a question for no apparent reason after there has been an answer. I voted to undelete.

Answer (score 5):

**Reopened, Closed as dupe (as proposed)**

[This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34350/242) meta question on strange keyboard behavior was closed for clarification (and currently has a delete vote). It has since been updated to clarify that the problem was due to the (little known?) SE keyboard shortcuts - which can cause very puzzling problems if one is not aware of them.

As such, I propose to reopen then close it as a dupe of a [prior related question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20760/242) on unexpected behavior caused by keyboard shortcuts. This will help improve matches to searches on such puzzling problems when they arise for other users. That no one on our meta recognized these shortcuts as the source of the problem seems to imply that giving this wider exposure here would be a good idea - not only to avoid wasting time debugging such strangeness, but also to give the shortcuts wider exposure to those who may find them useful.

Comment: I cast the last reopen vote and first close vote as dupe of proposed question, just now.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate now. (I could not help here because I cast a close vote on the original version of the question.)

Comment: Thanks to all. Hopefully this will help others to avoid pulling their hair out on encountering one of these strange interactions.

Answer (score 4):

**Undeleted**

Please undelete [Functional Analysis: Finding finite functions over different norms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3847832/290189) as the question asker self-deleted his/her own question one day after receiving an answer.

Comment: @Jethalal Yes, OP can do self-delete his/her own question if it has only one answer with a score ≤ 0.  I've posted plenty of answers like this for a few years under this undeletion thread (and its "dupes"): https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30294/290189, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30281/290189, …

Answer (score 4):

**Reopened**

Please consider reopening [Looking for a Simple Proof of the Divergence of the Prime Harmonic Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302207/looking-for-a-simple-proof-of-the-divergence-of-the-prime-harmonic-series).  It is a natural question of wide interest and has a very clear implied context, of a teacher who wishes to present an elementary proof of a famous theorem to calculus-level students.  It is not clear to me what additional context the close voters would have wanted or how the site would be better off without this question and others like it.

Comment: Not sure if there is a canonical post on this series yet. One candidate is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-converge), another one with an interesting proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923355/is-the-series-sum-1-infty-frac1p-j-where-p-j-is-the-jth-prim?noredirect=1&lq=1). It seems that one should make a canonical one by merging several posts.

Answer (score 4):

**Reopened**

Please consider reopening [Is there a metrizable topology on tempered distributions for which sequential convergence is pointwise?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4163056/is-there-a-metrizable-topology-on-tempered-distributions-for-which-sequential-co).  This question was originally unclear but the asker has clarified what they meant.  The question was also difficult to understand due to (I assume) a language barrier combined with some imprecise phrasing, and I've cleaned it up to be much clearer.

Answer (score 3):

**UNDELETED but still CLOSED**

I want to know why the reason for closure of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964221/prove-that-minor-of-any-order-of-an-orthogonal-matrix-a-is-equal-to-its-cofact) question has been given as:

> Questions about choosing a course, academic program, career path, etc. are off-topic. Such questions should be directed to those employed by the institution in question, or other qualified individuals who know your specific circumstances.

I do not see any reason for closure of this question.

Comment: The close reason is, I think, nonsense.  However, the question does (in my opinion---note that I say this not as a moderator, but as a disinterested third party) deserve to be closed.  It lacks context.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Well, in that case am I permitted to delete the question because it is not useful for anyone anymore? And secondly, can you explain what more context could I have added in there? I didn't understand the statement of the question itself, so what ideas should I have been added there? Note that I know how to ask good questions on this site, as you can see my profile.

Comment: See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  In your case, I would suggest that the problem seems to depend on the definitions of "cofactor" and "minor".  Quoting those definitions in your question would likely help to provide context (of course, a careful reading of those definitions might also clear up the confusion).

Comment: I should also point out, again, that when I say that the question should be closed for lack of context, I am merely expressing my opinion.  I am not expressing the opinion of the moderating team, nor making a statement about site policy.  I left the question in the state it was in an hour ago, but with a close reason that makes more sense.  Other users may disagree, and may feel that the question ought to be reopened.  That said, providing additional context will make it easier for others to vote to reopen.

Comment: The question has been deleted.

Comment: I am unsure whether it was appropriate of me to cast the last needed undelete vote, which I did.  I agree with the previous comments, and my normal take on such a situation is to re-open the question, eliminating the nonsensical reason for deletion, to give the OP a chance to improve the posting.  I question whether what I did is appropriate, because so much time has passed.  If not for the nonsensical reason for the deletion, I wouldn't have touched the question.

Answer (score 3):

**Reopened**

I asked a question about an identity involving large uniform random numbers here: [Prove that $\lim_{m \to \infty} (\lceil m U \rceil -mU ) \sim U(0,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4139501/prove-that-lim-m-to-infty-lceil-m-u-rceil-mu-sim-u0-1). The question is part of a larger theme of questions around proving a general result about point processes. I intend to write a paper on this topic and want to link these questions in the paper. It becomes harder to link questions that are closed like this and I also want to be able to add answers there in case I find a better, shorter way to prove the result in the future.

It was my mistake for not adding enough context, but I've done that now and linked to the other question. Can someone please re-open the question or let me know what other context I can provide to make it acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

**undeleted, reopened**

Please undelete the following question:

[Union of closed convex sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4141455)

The question and (my - to be fair) answer was highly upvoted. The question was closed/deleted for lack of context. I edited the question to include some context: The claim seems to be true in situations one can immediately think of. It is one example of a claim on convex sets that seems to be true, but isn't.

Answer (score 3):

**Undeleted.**

Requesting to undelete ["Trace identity for symmetric matrix"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4301695/trace-identity-for-symmetric-matrix).

The OP responded to some clarifying comments by me and Ben Grossmann, but after I posted my answer, they deleted their comments as well as the entire question.

Comment: In the future, you might consider raising a flag when something like this happens.  I, personally, frown on the behaviour exhibited here (deleting a question immediately after getting answer).  I believe that the other moderators feel similarly.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thank you, I wasn't sure if it was appropriate to use the "Flag" option for this situation (given the existence of this thread). I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2):

**Reopened**

The author of [Generating function of the number of permutations of length n with exactly k fixed points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4216110/generating-function-of-the-number-of-permutations-of-length-n-with-exactly-k-fix) has added the source of the question and the solution for half of the question. I think that the question has an interesting answer and I would like to post it.

I would like to see this question reopened.

Comment: You could have waited a bit before the reopen review queue finishes (the second point in the guidelines)

Comment: Oops. I was involved in the OP's efforts and forgot. Sorry.

Comment: This should be reopened, the justification would be that is that it follows the guidelines now. Having said that, I've seen the timeline, and please try to improve questions before formulating answers for them (I see you have created and deleted an answer and then made an improvement comment, hence this request). I know that people can get carried away with mathematical content, but please make sure that you are seeing the other side of things as well, namely the fact that you want to be making this question better(as you recognize it has site-based flaws) and then answering it.

Comment: I saw the lack of context and deleted my answer very quickly (under 2 minutes, during which time the OP was logged off). I encouraged the author to add some context, which they did. Does the presence of a deleted answer encourage PSQs? I will not undelete my answer until the question is reopened. As for *when* an answer is formulated, I know that once I see an interesting question, I'd have a hard time not thinking about it until the question is improved.

Comment: I am happy the question reopened, but I am surprised that you wrote the answer and then noticed the issue that it was a PSQ. I think you should spot this fairly quickly and leave an improvement comment before answering the question. If you are not seeing the merits/ demerits in the question vis-a-vis the site before answering it, then I request you to be more careful and/or ask in chatrooms.

Answer (score 2):

**Closed, Reopened, Closed by mod, deleted**

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323973/is-the-sum-of-elements-of-a-nontrivial-subgroup-of-mathbb-z-p-zero?noredirect=1&lq=1) question has never been asked before on this site (nor a direct generalisation\restriction). However it was associated with two questions which each have an answer that contains a solution (or can be generalised to a solution).   The question has as a result been deleted.

[One](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125027/why-is-the-sum-modulo-n-of-elements-in-mathbbz-n-equal-to-0) of the associated questions has one answer, which has since been edited (at the request of the person who originally closed the present question) to include an argument which can be generalised to answer the deleted question.  It is still not completely natural, as it does not fully answer the question it is supposed to answer.

The [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357086/infinite-sum-of-elements-in-a-finite-field/) question is even less related, but is slightly open ended so one of its answers included an answer to the deleted question.

In my opinion, given how simple and standard the question is, it is worth being asked and answered once on this site, even if solutions can now be dug up in two answers to other questions.

Comment: For the record, there was/is in fact a 2nd dupe link  (and comment) pointing to the  [identical proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1357145/242)  in "other question". The common simple (2 line) proof posted in the current question is *exactly* the same as the proof linked in the  2nd dupe (and also exactly the same as that in the first dupe after the appropriate (obvious) specialization). There is nothing at all novel in the answer in the current question. This well-known proof has been posted here *many* times.

Comment: @BillDubuque If "This well-known proof has been posted here many times", then surely a better duplicate-target exists? I mean, it isn't immediately clear how to extract the answer here from *either* duplicate-target. Remember the links are to questions, not answers, so we have one related-but-different question (where we are supposed to notice that an incorrect answer is the one we are after), and one basically irrelevant question, where the non-accepted answer contains the relevant argument. Irregardless of the arguments being relevant, the duplicates are *bad*.

Comment: (Of course, someone could edit [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/125038/10513) to point out that primality is used, or could have posted a CW answer to the question being discussed explaining the connections. But the current situation is unhelpful to anyone trying to extract this knowledge.)

Comment: @user1729 Re: "extraction" Not true! When I closed it as a  dupe I posted links to the *answers*  containing the proofs.  Please read more carefully before making *unfounded* critiques.  The proofs in the dupes are *exactly* the same as the proof posted currently so it's not clear why you think they are "bad". All of this was already covered in comments there, so I am not going to repeat it again here. Please *fully*  read the thread before commenting here.

Comment: @BillDubuque Sure there are links in the comments, but the main links (beneath the line "This question already has answers here:...") are to questions. I justify the badness in my comments - I do not dispute the "sameness" of the proofs, but am criticising the difficulty in extracting these arguments from the links. But more than that, I am suggesting you *do* something about it - don't just point at the links/answers, but, for example, correct the incorrect proof. (And I have read the thread fully.)

Comment: Again, there is no such "extraction difficulty" because I gave in comments the links to the specific answers containing the proof  - as I often do - to help guide the OP.

Comment: @tkf Could you *please* correct your post to reflect the fact that question *has* in fact  "been closed in association with the other question", cf. the 2nd dupe link. Did you miss that?  You claim you would not object so strongly if that were true, and it is in fact true.

Comment: @amWhy Thankyou for your comments.  Even if no further explanation is given, I really appreciate you giving your honest opinion, and I am sorry it has gotten you berated.

Comment: Regarding the above off-topic and highly  misleading comments by amWhy. My comments to her simply remarked that I was disappointed that she reopened some dupes, and asked her to please be a bit more careful in reviews (we all know that they are often done too too hastily). My comments were far more polite than many of the scathing critiques that have often been placed in CRUDE. They are still there so this can easily be confirmed.

Comment: Her [reply](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59795701#59795701) was "Apologies. All I can say is "oops". I had not payed attention in the reopen review queue". How one can go from that to the above tirade is beyond me (actually not completely so since there is a long history of such, but that is off-topic here).

Comment: I honestly don't know about this one. I am sympathetic to the idea Bill Dubuque seems to support here. That we could close questions as duplicates of an answer to a slightly different question. because the answer applies here equally well. IIRC I have pressed for something similar in the past. Then again, this is not the umpteenth replica. I could not find many other targets. I don't know if my gut feeling to let this one stay is defensible? *Close the twentieth argument reuse at the slightest excuse, but require a more exact match if it is only the fifth*. Doesn't sound good, does it?

Comment: @Jyrki If one works against the innate abstraction that helps to organize mathematics then any hope of organizing this site is ultimately doomed.

Comment: @BillDubuque I see you have requested that the answer to the first alleged dupe be fixed, so that it becomes a dupe for my answer.  First thankyou - clearing up the incorrect mathematics is a priority.  However it raises two issues.  Given that my answer already exists, surely if and when the other answer is made the same as mine, it would then be a dupe of my answer, rather than the other way round?    Secondly, it would not be entirely relevant, as it would address a generalisation of a restriction to the question it is supposed to answer.  If duplication is to be avoided, why create one?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I would be happy with even one answer to a slightly different question, so if you know of any, that would resolve this.  Of the two posited, the one regarding $(\mathbb{Z}_n)^*$ is very different as it does not address subgroups, and if it did the statement would be false: $1+3=4 \neq 0 \mod 8$.  The answer there was given by mistake - I do not think it would be given as an answer, with the restriction to primes, given there were already complete answers there to the question asked.  The other is a request for intuition about infinite sums.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen On the other hand I do take your point about argument reuse.  If it is the policy to only ever allow one instance of any given argument, regardless of the question, then I accept that of the three, your one is the one that should remain, as it is the earliest correct use of the argument.

Answer (score 2):

**Reopened**

Please consider reopening [If the image of an operator is closed, is the image of the powers of the operator also closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4324678/if-the-image-of-an-operator-is-closed-is-the-image-of-the-powers-of-the-operato).  This is a very natural question to which there are no immediately obvious counterexamples, and it has received a very nice answer.

It seems to me that this is exactly the sort of question that this site was built for: questions that may naturally occur to many people (not just some exercise that is of no particular interest), do not have obvious or "standard" answers that can be found in every textbook on the subject, and by having an answer here the answer will be easily findable with a search engine.

Comment: If a link to a question reveals it to be closed, will it remain closed? :)

Comment: To be honest : for this question, I think you can consider a context rewrite if you are interested. For some context : [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638640/compact-operator-with-closed-range-has-finite-dimensional-range) shows that if $T$ is compact with closed range then the range is finite-dimensional. Now, if $T$ is compact, so is $T^n$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$ (product of compact operators remains compact) : therefore, $T^n$ also has finite-dimensional and hence closed range. Right now , I think it should remain closed, but looks good for a context rewrite.

Comment: Minor correction to the above : if $T$ is compact with closed range then $T$ is finite dimensional, so $T^n$ is finite dimensional (don't need to use any product-compact results) hence has closed range.

Answer (score 1):

**Undeleted**

An answer of mine to
[Resources, references, or examples for logics with finitely many sentences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982975/resources-references-or-examples-for-logics-with-finitely-many-sentences) was deleted via review.

May I kindly ask to reconsider this deletion. My answer relates to the observation that finite problems are always trivial in the context of computational complexity (see, e.g., the accepted answer [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83752/any-problem-whose-domain-is-finite-is-always-decidable-is-true-or-false?)). The OP requested some clarification under my post, and I would have gladly given this clarification but my answer was already deleted then.

EDIT: It seems that I could undelete the question myself and provide the clarification. Is this the recommended way to proceed?

EDIT: I took the liberty of undeleting myself.

Answer (score 1):

**[Undeleted, deleted (by Community user, as "abandoned")](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3998706/revisions)**

Please undelete [Group theory question of red and blue blocks](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3998706) as the question asker has self-deleted his/her own question a few hours after receiving an answer from a trusted user.

Comment: Trusted users should be trusted not to answer copy-paste homework questions.

Answer (score 1):

**Re-opened.**

Please reopen:

[A Basic Limit From Exponentials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4034344/a-basic-limit-from-exponentials)

I believe this is *not* a duplicate of [How does one prove that $e$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312038/how-does-one-prove-that-e-exists) which was why it was closed.

The question from the first link asks why the limit $\ \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2^x-1}{x}\ $ exists. Whereas the question from the second link asks to prove that there exists a number $a$ such that $\ \displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h - 1}{h} = 1.$

Answer (score 1):

**Undeleted and reopened**

Please consider undeleting and reopening [Is an ideal finitely generated if its radical is finitely generated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4043247/is-an-ideal-finitely-generated-if-its-radical-is-finitely-generated).  This is a very natural question to which there are no immediately obvious counterexamples, and it has received a couple nice examples in answers.

It seems to me that this is exactly the sort of question that this site was built for: questions that may naturally occur to many people (not just some exercise that is of no particular interest), do not have obvious or "standard" answers that can be found in every textbook on the subject, and by having an answer here the answer will be easily findable with a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

**Reopened**

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4074358.

I have also voted for closing the question as a duplicate but retracted the vote after the question was edited.

It is clear from the content of the edited question that its issue was a search  for an error in the OP solution (and not for a correct way of solving the problem). In this sense it is certainly not a duplicate of the linked question. In any case as soon as the link to the alleged duplicate was given OP stated that (s)he is interested only in finding the own error.

I should admit that the linked question also started with an error (a different one) and this error was not addressed in any answer (but in one of the comments).

Quite generally I would assume that the most questions aimed on search of own error (or solution verification) cannot be treated as a duplicate.

Comment: After you cast the reopen vote, the post automatically went into the reopen review queue. If you wait until the review complete, you might not need to post the request here (This is mentioned in the "guidelines" of this thread").

Comment: I agree and will next time follow the guidelines. Thank you for pointing my attention to this.

Answer (score 1):

**Reopened**

Please consider reopening this question

[Find the range of values of $θ$, such that $θ\in[0,2π]$ for which $(\cosθ,\sinθ)$ lies inside a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4120132/find-the-range-of-values-of-%ce%b8-such-that-%ce%b8-in0-2%cf%80-for-which-cos%ce%b8-sin%ce%b8)

this question is completely understandable as all the equations are now written in math JAX also it might have happened that people who were unable to solve the question have reported it. This question is from a verified text and I can prove that the question is 100% correct and it's the case of false reporting.

At last, I request once again to
please consider reopening this question

Answer (score 1):

**Reopened**

Three days ago, [Asymptotic expansion of $\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^k \frac 1 {1-x^k} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179268/asymptotic-expansion-of-sum-k-1n-n-choose-k-1k-frac-1-1-xk) received three close votes due to lack of context. Since then, the author added clarification and context. Yesterday, there were two close votes arising from a review, and those closed the question. However, I think that this poster has shown a decent effort to improve their post.

The question is interesting and I request that this question be reopened.

I apologize that I forgot to mention that I have answered this question.

Answer (score 1):

**Undeleted**

Please consider undeleting this [meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33798/the-assumption-of-knowledge-of-what-notation-means).

I don't have enough reps to see the post now, so I might miss the reason why the OP deletes the post. But the question they ask are quite legit and there are some useful discussion in the comment.

Comment: Hmm. I’m not so sure if I should vote to undelete as it was deleted by OP themselves. (In general I use far fewer review type votes on meta...) I guess it was due to the overall negative reaction. If you want I can copy the comments somewhere, if you wait for me to reach a computer

Comment: Thanks, @CalvinKhor It's not that I particular want to see the discussion again. I just feel that that is a good question to ask (it's a shame I had to downvote it) and the discussion there should be useful to stay.

Comment: Well, here is the discussion anyway: https://imgur.com/a/kWBXfYN as you can see, there is one undelete vote atm.

Comment: You could of course ask the question again yourself?

Comment: @user1729us yes, but the discussion is already there.

Comment: I've voted to undelete because it's worth resuming discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

**[Undeleted, redeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3997519/revisions)**

Please undelete [Given a $1 \times n$ board and $4$ colors including white,red,yellow,blue](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3997519) as the question asker has deleted his/her own question after receiving a well-written answer.  That's not something we wish to see after spending effort on other's question.

Comment: For future reference, "The asker deleted the question immediately after getting answers" is something that may be worth raising a flag over.

Comment: When this question was deleted by the user who posted it, @Xander commented, "Please do not delete your questions after getting an answer. This is disrespectful to the people who provided answers to your question, and is disrespectful to people in the future who may be interested in the question and answers here." So isn't it still disrespectful to those future users, to delete it by vote now?

Answer (score 0):

**Re-opened.**

Please reopen [Less common probabilities and expected values related to the coupon collector problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4020223). It is falsely closed as a duplicate. Though the question brought in the title is indeed very often it is **not** asked in the body of OP.

Particularly the question asks about the expected value of collected unique cards after a certain number of trials, not about the expected number of trials to collect a certain number of unique cards. Though the former question is probably have been already asked and answered here, it is certainly not that one which was linked as "original".

Comment: What you say about not being a duplicate is true, but this is so because the OP asks multiple questions.  By itself that is not a fatal flaw (the problems are closely related), but the Question provides no context.  It appears to me to be a "pass through assignment".  If you like the Question enough, perhaps leave a  comment for the new user to provide context, or repost the problem with your own context.

Comment: @hardmath OP indeed asks multiple questions. But none of the questions is asked or answered in the alleged "original". I would not complain if the question was closed because of "providing no context". This would stimulate the author to correct it. But  the given link certainly will not help him or her to find the correct answers.

Comment: @hardmath That would be great.

Comment: After a bit of research I chose one of the coupon-collectors Questions that asks about the probability distribution aspect, and which not only has a decent Answer but also links to many other Questions of a similar nature.  Of course the expected value problems are easier than working out the probability distributions (after $x$ cards bought), but the OP has done literally nothing to motivate writing out a new Answer.

Comment: @hardmath The given link is of course very interesting but it does not address the asked questions, neither do the links inside. Though I agree that it can help to point out the direction (if the asker has  a solid background).

Answer (score 0):

### **Undeleted, reopened, reclosed (as duplicate)**

Yesterday I posted this [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4083595/how-to-compute-the-integral-displaystyle-int-0-infty-frac1-sqrt2-pi-t-c?noredirect=1#comment8439222_4083595) question.   When I checked it last night, it had the two sound-looking answers you see.  I woke up today to find it had been not just closed but completely deleted.  This seems to me completely preposterous.   It's pretty clearly not a homework question, but a reasonably deep integral computation that I had no idea how to begin.  I'd be happy to provide more "context" (1. unnecessary though that evidently was for the people who answered it, and 2. as if the identity isn't interesting in its own right) but the post is completely deleted and so I was given no opportunity to do so in anything like this site's notion of a timely manner.  Is there some way I may be allowed to provide the all-important context in order to reopen the question so that I can at least reward the people who helped me?

Comment: So you can just go to the deleted question (which you can get to from deleted recent questions in your profile) and copy the address from there an users with >10K rep can view it and possibly vote to undelete it. Posting an image here with no link makes anyone but a moderator unable to help you.

Comment: @MattSamuel I see, thanks. I've added the link

Comment: Can't you edit the deleted post? Asking for undeletion before improving your post (and not mentioning the fact that there's a linked duplicate in the comments) seems premature.

Comment: @KReiser. I see the duplicate now, and am ok with it staying deleted for that reason only.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: still seems a bit of a shame that the very nice answers will be lost

Comment: just for the record though, it is as i thought -- i get the "This post has been deleted -- no more edits are allowed" when i try to edit it. @KReiser

Comment: Hmm, I was unaware of that restriction on editing deleted questions.

Comment: The post has been undeleted (it is still closed. Perhaps it should be better closed as a duplicate)

Comment: Thanks you for improving the question - it is much better now. I voted to both close and delete this question at the time because it was simply the statement of a question without any context or effort or anything. I would have acted similarly if you had been a new user, but my actions were particularly heartfelt because you are *not* a new user, and instead have been here for almost 10 years and have picked up 5k rep. points. So you surely *must* have picked up on what is expected of a question by now...

Comment: @user1729 I don’t know if this is the proper place to discuss this, but since you’ve made the same comment twice now I’ll respond by saying that I and a non-negligible minority of other users of the site don’t share your expectations that a post contain “context” or exhibitions of failed attempts when those things aren’t likely to help people answering it.  My post is a good example.  You say the post is now “much better,” but I think you’d be hard pressed to explain how what I’ve added about resolvents of Brownian motion would make it easier for someone to help me.

Comment: @Timkinsella Its not about someone being better able to help you, per se, although you have now given the book where they could look it up in (which is helpful when people misquote a problem, or the problem requires a result proven earlier in the book, etc.). There are other reasons for providing context too, including basic politeness, but also: We live in a world where the vast majority of exams are not in exam halls (for example, my uni has 24 hr take-home exams), so giving some context and providing some effort stops your question getting lumped in with the obvious cheaters.

Comment: That is totally leaving aside your decision to vote to completely *delete* the question so soon after it was asked for the reason that it lacks context, a reason that calls for the OP to improve the post which he cannot do when the post is deleted @user1729

Comment: @Timkinsella Sure. I would have been more lenient if you hadn't been here for almost 10 years with lots of rep. points.

Comment: As one of the original close voters I should probably declare that I had the exact same thought process regarding voting to close. There so many questions that it's not effective for those that "stand on their own merits" to be vetted for quality by non-experts (e.g. experts in other fields), and the close voting is democratized. Writing for Math.SE is different from writing for a book. If you think there is a better (and **scalable**) alternative to separating the wheat from the chaff other than adding context, you should try to post a question on meta to persuade the majority.

Comment: @CalvinKhor  If “wheat” = “questions that very probably didn’t come from a freshman calculus exam”, then I don’t really know what level of expertise you’re talking about. Behind this fixation on “context” and documentation of failed attempts I see no actual criteria for judging the quality of questions beyond an extremely crude correlation with the mere *length* of the post.

Comment: For instance, I wonder how a user might ask the same question I asked if it were merely posed to him, with no context, by a classmate? He has no context to offer you; are you going to believe he’s a curious student asking in good faith? Or are you going to fire off a passive aggressive comment about effort and expectations and delete his post? Seems like a tough choice if you’re philosophically opposed to actually thinking for a few moments about questions before you judge their quality.

Comment: @Timkinsella (A) i know some maths people I class as 'smart' who wouldn't be able to compute an integral even at gunpoint. They just forgot things they don't use. (B) me too, there isnt much other criteria. So whats the alternative? (C) there are lots of rambly (= long) closed posts. (D) That's easy; documented failed attempts. Or more charitably, why the integral is interesting. and (E) I cannot believe he is a curious student asking in good faith because there are too many students on the site. Come by my office and its a different story.

Comment: @user1729 Frankly I wonder whether that’s true, and not just because you explicitly said the opposite in your first comment above.

Comment: @Tim "similarly"=giving the user more time, posting a different and more helpful comment. If they did not edit then I would still vote to delete.

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened**

I'm not sure why this question was closed. I feel like the OP is maybe slightly unclear about what possible methods there might be for finding the coefficients, but the problem they are trying to solve is clear and answerable (It is upvoted and has an accepted answer (**Disclosure:** The accepted answer is mine).

[Can we determine higher powers of a matrix in terms of lower powered matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170557/can-we-determine-higher-powers-of-a-matrix-in-terms-of-lower-powered-matrices)

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened**

Please consider reopening [Example of a map of coverings which is not a covering map, if the base space is not locally path-connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4199404/example-of-a-map-of-coverings-which-is-not-a-covering-map-if-the-base-space-is).  This is a natural question asking for an example to show that a certain technical hypothesis is needed in a well-known basic theorem in the theory of covering spaces. The original version of the question was missing a crucial assumption and as a result didn't make much sense, which I believe was the reason the question got its first few close votes.

It seems to me that this is exactly the sort of question that this site was built for: questions that may naturally occur to many people (not just some exercise that is of no particular interest), do not have obvious or "standard" answers that can be found in every textbook on the subject, and by having an answer here the answer will be easily findable with a search engine.

[Disclosure: I have answered the question.]

Comment: Actually I was about to post the request, and you are correct in evaluating my close vote there.

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened**

I come here for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207566/residues-of-powers-modulo-a-squarefree-integer) question.

The background of this question is as follows : it initially contained a single supporting statement along with the problem statement. It was closed , then the author edited the question to reflect their surprise at the closure and mention that the question arose from idle curiosity (i.e. sufficient context was , in my opinion, not added). This edit fetched reopen votes until it was rolled back, by which time it had opened again.

However, the post had been revised post-reopening : the setting of the problem is clearer to see, and the level of answer required has been clearly emphasised, as has the source  of being an "idle curiosity" (we can argue over if it counts or not). So that's source (I take it to be a honest admission) and background/type-of-answer-sought sorted.  It has now been closed again, however.

I would like the post to be judged on its current merit for the purpose of reopening. I would also like people to debate if context rewrites are required for this question or not, and what content will be suitable for this (Note : the page for admissible context rewrites is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/guidelines-for-context-edits-and-rewrites) and my opinion is that the setting and the problem statement could do with a link statement).

Comment: Poor judgement here, Teresa.

Comment: @amWhy All my reopen requests here (with probably one exception way below this if I'm not wrong) were made in poor spirit and with the intention of trying to clarify what was wrong with some posts which I felt were not wrong. All of them got clarified on CURED. I'm not sure I will be doing this again, but I'll have to work hard to gain your confidence in this statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened**

Please reopen [Solving $2\cos \left( \frac{\pi }{2}-\theta \right)=3\cos \left( \frac{\pi }{3}+\theta \right)$ for $0 < θ < 2π$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277190).

This question was closed as a duplicate by the Community bot, yet it is not remotely related to [Find all $x$ that satisfy $ 3 \cos{2x}=-1 $ for $0^{\circ} \leq x \leq 180^{\circ}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272455), or the previous versions of the question.

Comment: Has the Community bot gone rogue?

Comment: I've never seen this happen before. It's probably some bug in response to the OP's behaviour: they changed the entire question to ask a new question.

Comment: But the way I read the timeline, OP changed the question *after* the bot closed it. For what it's worth, the duplicate target had the same OP, who also changed *that* question.

Comment: That's why it's a mystery. The OP didn't change that question before the bot closed it, yet something about their other questions could have triggered it.

Comment: Never mind, this [meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30904/community-makes-content-edits) reveals that the OP marked their own question as a dupe on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Undeleted, deleted again**

[How can Irrational numbers go on forever](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4285969/) asks an elementary but reasonable mathematical question with a factual answer.  It  was closed as “needs details or clarity”, but I found it clear enough to answer.  (I think it should probably have been closed as a duplicate.)

Part of the purpose of Math SE is to be a repository of questions and answers.  Similar questions have come up before, so I was at some pains to write a clear answer that might prevent the question from coming up as often in the future.

Comment: If you thought "it should probably have been closed as a duplicate", why did you not vote to close it as a dupe, and worse, answer it anyway?

Comment: Despite their combative tone I will take your questions as asked in good faith. I often vote to close questions as duplicates, but doing so properly requires an effort to find an appropriate duplicate, and in this particular case I hoped that some other user might have one ready at hand. (It appears that so far, nobody else has been wiling to make the effort either.) And I wrote my own answer for the same reasons I answer any question: because I thought I could answer the question clearly and accurately, addressing the asker's particular confusions, and because I enjoyed doing so.

Comment: For the best interest of this site, please read [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|138.6079).  You are not exempted by declaring CW when you knowingly answer questions that are dupes, or answer PSQs.  There, you have been informed.  I'm done here.  Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Would it be possible to reopen: [Counting how many items can be weight on a scale if we pick the weights optimally](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3981347/counting-how-many-items-can-be-weight-on-a-scale-if-we-pick-the-weights-optimall?noredirect=1)
It has an accepted answer and is not the same as the post that is linked to.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think it is sufficiently answered by the other post, even if it is not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

**Closed and Deleted**

Please reopen
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021245/caching-in-magma?noredirect=1#comment8308788_4021245

The `magma-cas` is 100% mathematical software, and questions about it are not usually answered when posted on Stack Overflow. While the question is about how the software handles caching, MSE is the place to post this where it will most likely get an answer (and it has an answer; there are better answers that could be posted if it was not closed). It is also not a low-quality question that can be answered by pointing to the documentation.

**[Edit:]**  MSE is where to post about these programs (magma, sage, gap) to get answers. The takeaway from the meta post linked in the comments is that no other SE site has a dedicated tag for the Magma CAS- in fact posts there are likely to be confused for a different computational package with the same name. There is no online forum anywhere. These posts are of interest to mathematicians and mathematicians only.

Comment: To give the counter-argument, questions about implementation are *explicitly* noted as off-topic in the [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Algorithm implementation/design, computer simulation and modelling, etc. [might better be asked on] Stack Overflow".

Comment: @XanderHenderson That is not for the magma computer algebra system, it is for a different sortware package that is also called magma (though it looks like there are maybe a few random questions for the computer algebra system in there by mistake; they are told they are in the wrong place).

Comment: I've revised my comment.  Also, note that this has come up before: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22052/is-either-math-se-or-stackoverflow-an-appropriate-forum-for-questions-about-magm

Comment: Also relevant: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17119/about-output-of-a-function-of-magma (takeaway: "being software used by mathematicians, Magma questions are on-topic here.")

Comment: The question has been deleted.

Comment: I don't see how a question can be deleted "using high rep", Morgan. Questions can be deleted by a moderator acting alone, or automatically by the stackexchange software on meeting certain criteria, or by a sufficient number of users voting to delete, but not (to the best of my knowledge) by a single non-moderator user, no matter how many points that user has.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Apparently I was mistaken, and questions can be deleted with 3 votes only, even with an upvoted accepted answer and a nonnegative score. I was under the impression they needed 5.

Answer (score -1):

**Reopened**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221288/prove-that-bbb-e-w-j-1-cdot-w-i-cdot-w-k-0-where-w-sim-n0-sigm) is what I'm seeking to address. OP visited CURED, and I asked them for context and they've added it (source + definitions + partial attempt), in my opinion. I think this has passed through the reopen queue once (garnering three reopen votes), and so I'd like to use this thread to get this reopened.

My involvement : helping OP to add context, and while I did vote to reopen initially, I thought the dialog box didn't load properly the first time and therefore actually clicked the button twice. I didn't see that the reopen vote had actually got registered the first time and hence got retracted upon the second click . Now I can't vote to reopen it.

Comment: krrchmrtz? (Gesundheit?)

Comment: @GerryMyerson I swear I couldn't think of a word in English. I'll edit the post to be a little less harsh on myself. There, that should hopefully do it.

Comment: This is a new feature that one can retract reopen vote. Unfortunately the pop up looks very similar to the one for casting the reopen vote. I almost got tricked too....

Comment: @ArcticChar I will hopefully be more careful next time, it's already happened to me once but on that occasion I didn't post here, and it got reopened eventually.

Comment: I'm always grateful to learn to easy way (from mistakes of others)!

Comment: @hardmath I agree with you, although in this case I'd say I will probably make another mistake like this before being careful, that's how I usually am!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Now it is reopened

Comment: @JitendraSingh Thank you, although I did make some mistakes in helping this user, I hope that the general principles were in place during our discussion. I also thank you for providing criticism when needed of the way I helped OP.

Comment: Once again, Teresa. :/

Comment: @user21820 The action will be done, thanks for the information. I do not know the subject matter , otherwise I'd have offered to help out in the math as well.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Okay thank you very much. Feel free to ask me anything about the mathematical content, if you wish to learn it. =)

Comment: @user21820 I have clarified this in my room, stated it clearly. Thanks for the offer of teaching me : I will take it sometime!

Comment: I don't know what you mean; your statement implied that I was also wrong. Why? And that user even ignored your statement, that's why I said "never admits". Regardless of this, I'd be glad to teach you if you want, but I'm definitely disappointed that you allow such behaviour to continue. If you don't want to explicitly say anything, at least move those messages to trash.

Comment: @user21820 I'm in conversation with the user : you are right that I was ignored. I'm sorry, I will have to be more firm, and will be so.

Answer (score -1):

I am perplexed by the deletion of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4244037), and would recommend it for undeletion. (Full disclosure: I answered the question, which is what made me aware of its disappearance.) The question was flagged as "spam or offensive content," and the user (who, if I recall correctly, was a new contributor) has been removed, but the edit history shows no indication of vandalism, and comments from the user, unless some have been deleted, all seem civil and on point.

Comment: The account is new, but it is the same person who keeps on forming new accounts to circumvent their (original) account suspension.

Comment: @ArcticChar, that would certainly explain the removal of the user. I assume the flagging as spam and deletion of the question are an automatic part of such removals.

Answer (score -2):

[Why is $\sqrt{-1}$ the only imaginary number we define?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230076/why-is-sqrt-1-the-only-imaginary-number-we-define) was closed as a duplicate of [Why don't we define "imaginary" numbers for every "impossibility"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259584/why-dont-we-define-imaginary-numbers-for-every-impossibility) and then deleted. It's not really a duplicate, though. The older question only mentions $x=x+1$ and $x=1/0$, while the newer question mentions $\log0$, $1/0$, and $(-1)!$ (that's factorial, not exclamation). Please consider voting to undelete, as there are things to discuss in the newer question that are absent in the older one.

Full disclosure – I posted an answer to the question.

Comment: The question cited above seems to be asking about a lot of things.  There are numerous questions on Math SE about $1/0$ (for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900600/), and there are several questions about extending the factorial function.  If the question is really about "why can't we just introduce new numbers?", the fact that they give more examples doesn't mean that it isn't a duplicate of the question it was closed as a duplicate of.  If they are interested in *each* example, then the question is too broad.  I don't see any reason to undelete or reopen it.

Comment: And, after skimming all of the answers provided to the newer question, it seems to me that any one of them would also be appropriate for the older question.  Indeed, your answer is very similar to the one given by [Peter Smith](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/259596/) (you use the world "field", he says "addition and multiplication", but it is the same idea).

Answer (score -2):

**Question closed, reopened, closed again, deleted.**

Please undelete [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4248130) to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4248118/is-this-proof-correct-for-positive-semidefinite-matrices?noredirect=1

The question had been closed as a duplicate to the older question [Is it true that $A^2\succ B^2$ implies that $A\succ B$, but not the converse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510895/is-it-true-that-a2-succ-b2-implies-that-a-succ-b-but-not-the-converse/510999#510999) and my answer was consequently deleted by a moderator. Although the central statements in both questions are the same, the newer question specifically asked for a solution verification and was also tagged as such. So, it should not be viewed as a duplicate and my answer should be restored as well.

Comment: FYI: since this has been deleted by a moderator, users that are not mods cannot vote to undelete. For the record also: the answer has been converted to a comment; the question was reopened

Comment: The question, @Calvin, is closed and deleted.

Comment: @amWhy it is now, and I did notice; there is no need for me to leave a further comment on this as the body of the Answer is kept up-to-date. My earlier comment is timestamped, and I have been burned by deleting comments on meta before, so I will leave it.

Answer (score -2):

**Reopened**

question closed for too broad/unfocused even after it was edited to have only 1 question: [Whether or not a (cyclic and thus Abelian) group $\mathbb Z_{p^m}$ (prime power) is decomposable into (normal) subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288026/whether-or-not-a-cyclic-and-thus-abelian-group-mathbb-z-pm-prime-power)

I don't mean to be arrogant, but I think the previous close votes were for old versions. I think the 5th close vote was just trying to help the other 4 close voters whom I couldn't exactly notify to say 'hey ok post is now trimmed to 1 question now please undo close vote'.

If what I'm thinking is incorrect, then ok [please help me improve the post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34227/please-help-me-improve-post-closed-too-broad-unfocused-even-after-it-was-edited).

Comment: Reopened (but already has one vote to close again). I suggest you take the comments on the question seriously.

Comment: @GerryMyerson what did i do/not do?

Comment: What you did was you pissed off the one person who was trying to help you. That person knows what he's talking about. Read what he wrote, and think about it until you understand why he wrote it. And, no, I will not engage in further discussion of the matter.

Answer (score -2):

**Closed, reopened, closed, deleted (by OP)**

**Update** $ $ OP confirmed that the question "had a typo", and should be the polynomial in the proposed dupe, so re-closing with said dupe target is likely the best course of action.

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4330652/242) was originally gb-closed as a dupe of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994734/how-can-i-factor-x65x38?noredirect=1&lq=1), then left-closed in review (3-0), then gb-reopened. The question is incorrect as stated - it asks to prove an irreducible polynomial is reducible, but this is almost surely due to a typo (or misprint) in an exponent. Fixing that it yields a common problem - said dupe. The OP has not corrected the question so rather than leave open a confusing question to prove a false claim, I recommend reclosing it either with the proposed (corrected) dupe, or "needs details..."

Comment: Closed as "needs details" , I could have potentially closed as either but I felt that there are two conflicting narratives, and even though , at the end, it was asserted that the polynomial contains $5x^3$ rather than $5x^2$, the question post does not reflect this, and I can't see the benefit of marking this as a dupe when the question itself isn't clear. With $5x^3$, it is actually reducible, but with $5x^2$ it is irreducible. If the OP is gone, then I don't even see a point in keeping the question around as it stands.

Comment: @Teresa Agreed, there is no good reason to keep the question, so it doesn't matter much which way we close it.

Comment: I've just cast the first delete vote.

Comment: Dear Bill, this is the thread for requesting reopening and undeletion votes. Why are you adding a close/delete vote request here?

Comment: @KReiser As I stated when I devised the thread [9 years ago](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6424/242), it is intended for matters that require exceptional handling.

Comment: Whatever someone personally may have thought when developing an idea, it is the community's interpretation and application of the idea that matters. The question and title make it clear that this is only about reopen and undeletion requests. Requesting closure or deletion does not involve exceptional handling - these are done by flags and reviews.

Comment: @Nij We'll have to disagree about that.

Comment: It seems the wording was changed by quid in the 2018 version of the question, from "posts that may require exceptional handling (including) reopen and undeletion votes" to "posts that may require reopen and undeletion votes". The "etc." was also dropped from the title.

Comment: I do think that there are times when having a more permanent record of closures is important, e.g. for questions over a year old with >20 score, say. In these (hypothetical) cases, it shouldn't be up to the community to react, but to the closers to justify themselves in advance. And it makes sense for this thread to handle such exceptional  situations.

Comment: @user1729 One of the primary goals when I devised the original thread was to collect together (localize) in one thread *all* such exceptional processing  - not only to avoid excessive bumping on meta but also to expose on meta matters that might benefit from further meta discussion (e.g. which won't automatically happen for discussions in a chatroom). That was part of the reason I posted here, since it might spark meta discussion on how to best handle issues like this one.

Comment: @user1729 While it is likely it could have been handled just as quickly in CURED, that would have subverted broader meta exposure, which I think is unfair. The (broader) community should have some say on how we handle decisions like this, i.e. when there is almost  surely a typo / misprint (and it will be a dupe either way), and it is wasting a lot of (cumulative) community time reading all the comments to understand the context, then I think we should close it asap. But there may be other views on how to best handle this. Hence this post on meta in a thread (originally) designed for such.

Comment: @Nij I found some time to elaborate - please see the above two comments.

Answer (score -2):

**Deleted (by moderator)**

[THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4336883/442) should be reopened.  The question asks for the reduction formula.  The alleged duplicate answers that the closed form requires hypergeometric functions.  But that is irrelevant since the reduction formula does not.

Comment: Said user is asking for something that does not exist.  The said user has now, with the post you want to reopen, repeated the question three times, which itself is inappropriate. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336878/find-the-reduction-formula-for-int-fracd-t-left1-t2-rightm, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336878/find-the-reduction-formula-for-int-fracd-t-left1-t2-rightm, plus the one you link to.

Comment: All three have been essentially equivalent, all have been closed as a dupe.  Said OP already knows said reduction formula does not exist.  Let this question die with dignity; it does not need your life support, as it has no answer.

Comment: From the exchange under [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336791/find-the-reduction-formula-of-int-fracd-t-left1-t2-rightm), I think the OP had got what they want (thus I voted leave closed in the reopen review queue)

Comment: The original version is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4336791/).  I have deleted the other two duplicate versions.  I do not think that the question merits reopening, but I am not going to take any action there.

Comment: At this point in time, there is no benefit at all to having another question about the reduction formula (for integrals). The law of diminishing returns applied here states that each additional question adds fewer and fewer benefits to the site, and in fact, may even clog the site up.

Answer (score -2):

Please undelete [How is it sensible to pre-suppose that S(k) is true, if you verified merely the base step? What if S(k) is false](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4338029/1007307)? Karl's answer has 5 upvotes, and housed_off_space 1.

I concede it *MAY PROBABLY* duplicate [In proof by induction, what happens if P(n) is false for a specific case or the base cases are false? Can we still deduce meaningful conclusions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/926460).

Comment: Please do not use posts on meta to call out specific users.

Comment: @XanderHenderson sorry. i didnt know i can't write their names. i just wanted their feedback. but the deleting users appears on the deleted question? so this is public information?

Comment: It is one thing to say "Please undelete..."  It is entirely different to open your post with "These users deleted a question...".

Comment: Again, evolva  [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|129.8224).  Uploading images with no thoughts of your own, does not a good question make.

Comment: ^^^^^ Errr, now evolva = user.

Comment: ^^^^^ Errr, now NNOX Apps

Answer (score -2):

The wrong duplicate got closed. Closing was wrong way around.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/346620 extends Monty Hall problem THE MOST. There are $n$ doors, Monty Hall opens $s$ doors, and $t$ doors  are hiding cars.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/609552 is less general, because $t=1$. It presumes merely one car. **This should be the one closed as duplicate.**

Comment: Closing is for Questions; you have linked to Answers. It should be `https://math.stackexchange.com/q/608957/` and `https://math.stackexchange.com/q/346613/`. Also it seems [you were the one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGXmv.png) who sent the ball rolling 'the wrong way round'?

Comment: I think it good just the way it currently is.

Comment: @CalvinKhor oops. sorry. i meant the other way then.

Answer (score -4):

Undeleted, now **DELETED**

Please undelete [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194947/) question I asked and answered, and its answers. It is intended as a sequel of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194159/) question. Edit the question if possible. Thank you.

Comment: I think Lord Commander's comment is on point: instead of referring to another post maybe you could write down the pattern HERE. You should edit the question to explain the pattern.

Comment: As the Question was asked (and answered) by you, you have the primary responsibility for editing the body of the Question in accordance with your meaning.  It seems the primary objection is that you ask about establishing "a pattern" for certain indefinite integrals and at the same time ask those willing to help to tell you what that pattern is.  Ideally you will add some context around what "pattern" means to you or what descriptions of a pattern would be satisfactory for your purposes.  The lack of context is particularly challenging in cases like this.

Comment: oh no no no.... no one wants to see that big wall of formulas. I don't see what value this question/answer adds to the site.

Answer (score -4):

**Reopened, then deleted by Community User**

Request to open [For countably infinite $A$, can we find a unique $\left\{F_n\right\}$ that gives the smallest standard deviation times cardinality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4213941/for-countably-infinite-a-can-we-find-a-unique-left-f-n-right-that-gives)

I tried explaining further and giving an example.

If it's still unclear please let me know why?

Comment: I gave an example and further explained what I want? Why the downvote.

Comment: Voting to reopen, but have you asked a question similar to this before? Like on averages of some sort? Also, please continue to clarify questions on the main post as and when required, because I've sort of checked your post and I see a couple of things that might trouble me (for example, it is not clear to me what standard deviation means in the question part) but I'm not really asking for clarification, rather pointing things out that might need them. You've got four reopen votes now.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I made edits. Hopefully, it's better now.

Comment: It is better, thanks. Now at least I understand the post better, if not how I'd approach solving it (that's a different matter, of course!)

Answer (score -4):

**Closed, reopened, closed again, deleted**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4331172/how-does-a-capital-pi-work-when-there-is-an-expression-underneath-it) was closed as a duplicate, but it is narrower than the question of which it is alleged to be a duplicate (and the comments under the question clarify that), as can be seen from the fact that it will admit an answer along the following lines, which would not fit so well with that earlier question.

It asks about the meaning of the notation $\displaystyle \prod_{i>j}.$

**BEGIN DRAFT**

The notation without further context is ambiguous. It can mean:

- $\displaystyle \prod_{i\,:\,i\,>\,j},$ so that it is the product over all possible values of $i$ that are greater than $j,$ with $j$ fixed, so that the value of the product depends on $j,$ or
- $\displaystyle \prod_{j\,:\,i\,>\,j}$ so that it is the product over all possible values of $j$ that are less than $i,$ with $i$ fixed, so that the value of the product depends on $i,$ or
- $\displaystyle \prod_{i,j\,:\,i\,>\,j}$ so that it is the product over all possible values of $i$ and $j$ with $i>j,$ so that the value of the product does not depend on $i$ or $j.$

In the first case, $i$ is a bound variable and $j$ is a free variable.

In the second case, $j$ is a bound variable and $i$ is a free variable.

In the third case $i$ and $j$ are both bound.

If the index set is $\{1,2,3\}$ then according to the first alternative, we would have
\begin{align}
& \prod_{i\,:\,i\,>\,1} (a_i-a_1) = (a_2-a_1)(a_3-a_1). & \text{In this case, } j=1. \\[8pt]
& \prod_{i\,:\,i\,>\,2} (a_i-a_2) = a_3-a_1. & \text{In this case, } j=2. \\[8pt]
& \prod_{i\,:\,i\,>\,3} (a_i-a_2) = 1. & \text{In this case, } j=3.
\end{align}

If the index set is $\{1,2,3\}$ then according to the second alternative, we would have
\begin{align}
& \prod_{j\,:\,3\,>\,j} (a_3-a_j) = (a_3-a_1)(a_2-a_1). & \text{In this case, } i=3. \\[8pt]
& \prod_{i\,:\,2\,>\,j} a_2-a_j = a_2-a_1. & \text{In this case, } i=2. \\[8pt]
& \prod_{i\,:\,1\,>\,j} (a_1-a_j) = 1. & \text{In this case, } i=1.
\end{align}

[to be continued]

Comment: Since narrower, it follows under the more general dupe.  If this was posted by the asker, here, I'd consider the request, if they specified why they were struggling making the connection.  But reopening so you can answer, I'd suggest you instead post this as a specific case under the link to the valid dupe target.  In the comments, the OP already acknowledges, between the dupe, and DietrichBurde explanation there, they now understand.  It seems like this is more about your desire to answer, than the OP's needing more help.

Comment: The post had been reopened and another more suitable duplicate suggestion is in the comment section of the post.

Comment: @amWhy There is no difference between my desire to answer and my judgment that anyone wondering about what the question asks about would learn about it by reading my answer.

Comment: A [new duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3205650/10513) had been suggested, and here the question is basically the same ($\prod_{i<j}(j-i)$). Maybe you could post your answer there?

Comment: I agree, @user1729. +1  At the same time, Michael needs to show good faith, given his experience on this site, and knowledge that his answer was merely repeating what had already been said: good faith in searching for duplicates, prior to answering.

Comment: "Since narrower, it follows under the more general dupe." That is quite incorrect. Understanding why a special case is in fact a special case can be a substantial question in its own right.

Answer (score -4):

**Reopened, Reclosed, Deleted**

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4342155/what-makes-a-number-big

This question is perfectly clear but not expressed in a way in which someone knowledgeable in the language of mathematics would express it. I can't help suspecting that the reason for the "close" votes is either the poster's lack of knowledge of standard jargon or some blind spot in the minds of those who voted to close it prevented them from understanding it.

Comment: I  see you answered the question, as well, @Michael.  It is considered good practice to reveal one's only involvement in a question they advocate for reopening/undeleting.

Comment: @amWhy : Why? My "involvement" is only as someone who responded to the question. I am not responsible for anything at all about the content of the question.

Comment: @Michael: The reason to reveal your vested interest in the Question, having answered it and thereby gotten upvotes and (in this case) Accepted Answer reputation, is to be honest with Readers who may decide if your position on reopening is to be taken at face value.

Answer (score -4):

**Undeleted, re-deleted**

Please undelete [If a changes to b, then doesn't a + d = b? Why a(1 + d) = b?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4337810/1007307). It assists future readers, because it hankers after clarification of an existing question.  Apology if my question is too simple? Is there another Stack Exchange for middle school math?

Many thanks to Prof. Ethan Bolker, who answered the question and who disagreed with the closing of my question.

Comment: Do not delete postings in this thread unless there are serious concerns about them. You can downvote if you do not approve of a request but deletion goes a step too far.

Answer (score -5):

**[Undeleted, reopened, closed again, deleted again, undeleted again, deleted again](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4185354/revisions)**

Please consider undeleting my question:

[Is Kumar Eswaran's proposed proof of the Riemann Hypothesis correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4185354/is-kumar-eswarans-proposed-proof-of-the-riemann-hypothesis-correct)

I understand that it was closed on account of being too broad for math.se. However, the existing comments indicate that a clear answer should exist.

Moreover, the question is in relation to a somewhat significant mathematical claim which has generated a lot of interest. So, it should be useful as a reference and a target for duplicate questions.

Therefore, I believe that undeleting or even reopening the question might be worth considering.

Comment: This was discussed in the CURED chat room [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58509842#58509842).

Comment: I don't think this is a question of broadness or duplication. The point is, that the question is *inherently* off-topic, being a question of the form "is a certain paper correct/incorrect", and because the content of the question is not going to change with edits, it is landing up in this delete/undelete war. That reason is stronger than either broadness or duplication, to the extent that similar questions will be painted with the same "off-topic" brush. I did lean on the "undelete but close" stance (your arguments supporting the "undelete"), but right now I'm literally undecided.

Answer (score -6):

Not sure if this belongs here, but Community accidentally deleted this question that I answered:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977648/how-can-i-find-the-mass-of-the-pencil-cylinder/3977750#3977750

(for +10k)

Comment: Already been asked again here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979061/gcse-how-to-find-the-volume-of-a-pencil

Comment: That was not a mistake.  The question had a negative score and was closed, and the answer was neither accepted nor upvoted.  Thus the question was automatically deleted.

Answer (score -6):

Can you please undelete

1. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4156575?

Apologia for asking a downvoted question, but it feels wasteful for the two upvoted answers to disappear. My question is unique because it asks about the intuition behind defining $0.\overline{9}=1$. The author in my post, Ellenberg, proved this in the pages previous to that in my post.

2. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4156178? It was automatically deleted 8 hours ago by Community♦ because it got 1 downvote.

Comment: For better or worse, there are subjects around here that are sore spots for the community and have higher standards for questions regarding them: $.999\dots=1$ is one of these. I think there's potentially an interesting question in there (what do we mean when we say two numbers are equal?), but your presentation is not getting at that, and I'd like to see some improvement before voting to undelete.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for giving me some hope. Can you please edit my question? I don't know what you want to get at. You mention "there's potentially an interesting question in there", but  didn't I ask it already? I don't know what you mean exactly?

Comment: Please make one request per Answer (as stated in the Qusetion body). Also it is possible that someone put the downvote precisely to get it auto-deleted

Comment: The problem with your questions is that they are not so much about mathematics as about what a particular author (Jordan Ellenberg, who is that rare combination of fine writer and first-rate mathematician) means by a particular pair of sentences in a book written for a general, *non-mathematical* audience. (cont.)

Comment: However, a partial answer to your Riemann-Hypothesis-by-definition analogue to "defining" $0.999\ldots$ to be $1$ can be found in a sentence in Ellenberg's *Slate* article which your question linked to: "Cauchy said, we should simply define the value of the infinite sum to be 1. **And then he worked very hard to prove that this choice of definition didn’t cause horrible contradictions to pop up elsewhere.**" (boldface added for emphasis).

Answer (score -6):

**Deleted**

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4211826? As it is, it's terse and intelligible. What more "details or clarity" do you need?

Comment: It would be good to add the main question statement; maybe you could explain why you think it does *not* overcount; and a more minor point perhaps use simpler words than expatiate (had to check a dictionary to understand you)

Comment: I think the issue with the question is that I have to click on the link to understand what is going on. So try and summarise what's going on, so say something like: "I was reading an answer to a question here, and would appreciate some help in understanding some steps. The question is as follows: (quote question, include link). User String solved this by (summarise their approach, link to their answer). However, they said (current question as it is)". This way, users get an idea of what is needed *before* they click on the link.

Answer (score -6):

Pls undelete and reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4347582.

I edited my post ***a second time*** in accordance with [FShrike](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/815585/fshrike)'s [advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4347582/please-expound-to-a-16-year-old-the-formula-for-the-number-of-k-permutations#comment9072187_4347582).

Because a moderator deleted my post, I cannot UNdelete the post.  **Can you still review my edit?**

Comment: There is still some things that I'd like you to remove from your post (there is no need to *add* anything, as I see it). I have mentioned these as comments under your main post. Please attempt further edits. I feel for your daughter, but it is not appropriate to include such sensitive details in your post, given they may deflect from the original question and actually delay the service your daughter receives from this website.

Comment: @Delete-voter. Requests ("answers") in this thread should not be deleted, e.g. see [this moderator comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2021-today#comment159858_34421). This is a longstanding policy.

Answer (score -7):

**DELETED**

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3968820/does-the-binomial-expansion-of-a-negative-prime-number-yield-its-equal-and-oppo

What is unclear or lacking in details about this please? I notice the close came AFTER I posted the screenshot.

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32970/

Comment: I can't really see what to improve in that post. Unfortunately the question is complete : "make sense of something apparently mathematical said by somebody and written on a blackboard". It is not a bad question in terms of site rules, but the problem is it truly looks arbitrary to half the people who read it, so that results in a downvote for a question that is apparently of no use and insignificant. Anyway, voting to undelete, but I don't know what is going to be an answer at all, let alone a constructive one, from the discussion on the question.

Answer (score -7):

**Deleted**

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4217023? What's wrong with it? Undeniably, the multiple commenters understood my question perfectly.

Comment: Personally, I don't understand what it is that you are after (the question is unclear), and I fear that the structure of the question makes me think that it is too broad (in general, questions of the form "Is X related to Y?" are vague, open to interpretation, and not really appropriate for Math SE.  I would also argue that the two commenters *didn't* really understand the question (one pointed out that they have a mnemonic for remember stars and bars computation, which has nothing to do with fencepost errors; the other only stated that they *make* fencepost errors).

Comment: If I were asked this as an "interview" question, i.e. where some valuable stake was involved, the best I could do is say, No (and explain why).  You might have something more substantative in mind than the observation that the bars in "stars-and-bars" look like fence posts, but I recall from seeing your post before thinking that observation itself is too superficial to meet my threshold for context.

Answer (score -8):

**Deleted, Deleted**

Please reopen

1. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4159730/933737. This was closed for "needs details or clarity". But isn't my question detailed enough? What do you need?
2. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4157393/933737. This was closed for "opinion-based." I made question factual.

Comment: ‘Clarity’ can be lost when too much detail is provided.

Comment: In the future, please create a new answer for each post you want handled.  Regarding the second question, you have, as far as I can tell, *completely* changed the question twice.  This creates a moving target for answerers.  Please don't do this.  I have rolled back the  post to the original question asked.

Comment: The other post suffers from the same problem.

Answer (score -9):

**Deleted**

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4200541?

[Mike Earnest's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4200541/sum-limits-k-0n-k-binom2nk-n22n-1-overset-iff-vandermond#comment8718194_4200541) appears to jump the gun.

> This seems like an example of the XY problem. You are asking about how you can use method X to solve problem Y, when method X is actually useless for problem Y, and all you actually care about is solving problem Y. Because the literal question "How can I use X to solve Y?" has no answer, you'll get no help, whereas if you had just asked "How can I solve Y?", you would have gotten help.

I tendered reasons why I think method X can solve problem Y. If the answer is that "method X is actually useless for problem Y", then this should be an answer to my question, and my question shouldn't be closed.

Comment: The Question was posted on July 17 and the Comments posted at that time or next day are reflective of the concern that it is a jumble of ideas, not merely that what you want to do ("transmorgify $\binom{m}{r-k}$ into $k$") can't be done, but that it isn't clear what you are asking.  Potentially you have in mind a definite goal, but you failed to edit the body of the Question for more than a week after the concern with clarity was noted.  Do you now have an intention of revising the post?

Comment: @hardmath "Do you now have an intention of revising the post?" Yes, as always. I apologize for my confusing writing. Don't hesitate to edit my post.

Comment: @hardmath wrote that it isn't clear what you are asking. So hardmath can't edit your post. Only someone who knows what you really mean to ask can edit your question. And the person most likely to know what you really mean, is you.

Comment: Responding to "If the answer is that "method X is actually useless for problem Y", then this should be an answer to my question," the problem is that we cannot definitively prove that method X is useless for problem Y in this case, especially since it is so unclear what method X is.

Answer (score -10):

**Reopened, Reclosed, Deleted**

I would like to reopen the following question:

**[Can We Define A Measure $\mu$ Which Follows All My Requirments?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4141241/can-we-define-a-probability-measure-mu-that-follows-all-my-requirements)**

If not, please explain in detail what is unclear or what cannot be improved.

Answer (score -13):

**Deleted**

The following meta post is **obviously** clear and detailed; however, since it contains some criticism *a few* people dislike, it was closed **wrongly** (This reminds me of [Galileo affair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_affair)):

[Can busy people moderate the community well?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33890/656359)

Let us not allow *a few* users to *dominate* this community.

Comment: Generally, and especially in mathematics, when you start emphasizing the word obviously you should take a step back and work out *why* it is so obvious to you and no-one else.

Comment: Generally, when someone compares him/herself to Galileo, he or she should take a few steps back, and consider how this will appear to others.

Comment: Quoting the guidelines of this reopen-undelete thread: "Do not only post a request, like "request reopening of link". Instead, make a case for your concern. Yet keep in mind that it can be easier to get your request handled if you try to frame it in a way that takes the feedback the post received into account positively rather then seeking confrontation. Also, try to improve the post before posting here."