# How do we handle a chain of "duplicate" questions that are linked to a "missing context or other details" question?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, closed-questions, context

The following chain questions are currently **all** closed:

- [Proving that $\langle x, y \rangle$ is a not principal ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x, y]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4044158)
- [Non-principal ideal in $K[x,y]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1872667)
- [The ideal $I= \langle x,y \rangle\subset k[x,y]$ is not principal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110708)

Here is another chain:

- [$5^{e}+6^{e} \equiv 0 \pmod {11}$ for all odd numbers $e$ and for no even numbers $e$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3838508)
- [How to prove that $4^m + 5^m$ is divisible by 9 when m is an odd number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/893678)
- [Proof of $a^n+b^n$ divisible by $a+b$ when $n$ is odd](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/641443)

Moreover, the first two questions are marked as "duplicate" to the last one which is closed as "missing context or other details".

Because of the current status, no one can add a new answer to any of these "duplicates". This essentially blocks out any possible useful future contributions to the question (one of the questions in the chain), *assuming* that they are really "duplicates".

**How** do we handle such questions? Particularly, if one wants to add useful answers that may be significantly different from the existing ones, what can one do?

Comment: An alternative would be to write a "canonical question and answer pair", and nominate all of those questions as duplicates of the canonical Q&A you have written.  If you believe that you have a great answer to a poor question, it is often better to attempt to write such a canonical Q&A.

Comment: The question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110708/the-ideal-i-langle-x-y-rangle-subset-kx-y-is-not-principal already has 6 answers. Do you think you can write one more which would be genuinely different from other answers?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Well, assuming you are using the [generic "you"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you) in your comment, who knows?

Comment: I have voted to reopen  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd).

Comment: These things happen. Both the chains you dug out are FAQs. A dupehunter may not always find the most canonical target. Or, the best target has good answers, but the question (often old) has since been closed for missing context because the standards have evolved. It may be worth our while to discuss the wisdom of closing old questions with good answers, but also lacking context.

Comment: (cont'd) The motivation for closing (but not deleting) the question is exactly because several newer threads refer to it, so we should make it extra clear to the new readers that the question itself is poor by the current standards. Of course, the people who don't like closing poor questions with good answers may object. Anyway, the site is self-correcting on all trigger happy closures (I have been on both sides of such incidents), so they aren't worth much meta drama. [The dedicated thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34447/11619) is a neutral way of soliciting more opinions.

Comment: Now that you brought it up, I somehow doubt that in the latter chain the duplicate target is the first incarnation with "canonical answers". The date is telling. My guess would be that we surely handled that question to death earlier than 2014.

Comment: @martinsleziak I raised a similar issue here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34051/505767

Comment: One thing to notice is that search engines tend to prioritize questions that are older and have more views, which usually correponds to the original, so *most* people are not going to have to click through the dupe chain.

Comment: @ArcticChar It is reopened, and I'm thinking that your actions in this situation are perhaps the best in general.