# What are you supposed to do when your answer is deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

A week ago I found a question here that I could answer. I registered on the site and posted my answer. Just a couple of hours later, my answer was deleted by votes from three trusted users. I do not see any explanation as to why it was deleted. I could only guess what the reason was. Of course, I wanted to correct my answer so that it would be accepted. I edited it and then pressed the Undelete button. I waited two days. But nothing more happened. It doesn't seem like my actions put my answer into any review queue. Then I pressed the Flag button and wrote a text similar to this one. One day later I saw that my answer had one more undelete vote, from the moderator I assume. But since then nothing more has happened.

How is this situation supposed to be handled? Would it be better to just post my edited answer as a new answer instead?

The answer is to this question:
[Prove: If $E$ is a nonempty subset of natural numbers, then there exists an element $k$ in $E$ such that $k\in m$ for any $m$ in $E$ and $m \ne k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500114/prove-if-e-is-a-nonempty-subset-of-natural-numbers-then-there-exists-an-ele)

Edit:
I looked at [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 01/2021 - today)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2021-today) first. But I didn't want to claim definitely that my answer deserved to be undeleted. I just wanted someone to review my changed answer and either undelete it or else explain what was wrong with it.

Comment: Yes, there's no review queue for deletion/un-deletion of posts, and you have to go to meta. There's a [dedicated thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2021-today) on that. Or to [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured) if you have sufficient reps to use that.

Comment: I guess those "trusted users" thought your solution was not more helpful than the  hint from 8 years ago.  The OP asked for a hint, and accepted that hint.

Comment: I don't see your hint in response to the question, @Tony ?

Comment: @amWhy My first answer was just a hint. But since that answer was deleted, I expanded my answer to a complete proof.

Comment: @amWhy I looked at the Requests for Reopen ... Question first. But I didn't want to claim definitely that my answer deserved to be undeleted. I just wanted someone to review my changed answer and either undelete it or else explain what was wrong with it.

Comment: I give you credit for wanting to improve it.  But I think GEdgar hit the nail on the head with his comment above.  If the question had been asked today, it would likely not have been deleted, I'm sure.  But when you answer an 8 year old question, in which the asker wants only a hint, and a hint satisfied the asker, it's likely the answer will be considered unnecessary.  But I get it, with one's first few answers, it may feel safer to answer older posts first.  In any case, give a shot at answering a recent question at some point.  Good luck!

Comment: Also, @Tony  Thanks for interacting in comments!

Comment: @GEdgar I can't see how I could prove it with that hint. I agree with the comment made by Elliot under the hint.

Comment: The answer has been undeleted (but I see one vote to redelete).

Comment: I recommend saving for possible future use the URL (which you can still see and obtain the code-text for by clicking "edit" regardless of your reputation, I think) with the question title and/or a description of what you discuss, maybe on a MS Word document or somewhere else saved off-line. I've begun doing this for answers I've had deleted (because asker deleted the question, or the user was banned, or something else), for possible re-copying and reuse as the occasion arises, although thus far I haven't done this for any of them yet. [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3517466/13130)