# Reason for Deletion of my Answer?

Tags: support, moderators, deleted-answers

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Derivative of a functional and taylor series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3073107/derivative-of-a-functional-and-taylor-series/4290904#4290904)

I would argue that the answer provides enough context to the question to resolve it. At the minimum, the question cannot be resolved without giving this context first.

Why was the answer deleted?

Comment: Note that this post had been closed, since we have a dedicated thread for these kind of request/inquiry. Please post your request as an answer in [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2021-today)

Comment: Note also that the answer has been undeleted.

Comment: @ArcticChar I am aware of this thread but it's not an option for new users.